# Alert user if window.width is smaller then 950px jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to give an alert to the user once the `window().width()` is smaller then 950px. My JS looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowSize = $(window).width();

        if (windowSize < 950) {
            alert("test");
            console.log("screen width is less than 950px");
        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});​
```

But nothing happens, not even my `console.log()`.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: it is working fine...

Comment: If you put your code to jsfiddle, there's an invisible char at the end which breaks your code. See  [worked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58t7du5b/) and the [fiddle copied from your code](https://jsfiddle.net/8smgtuwf/). The original one will give you `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` at the end of the code.

Comment: No error in console? As a side note, to check viewport width, you'd have better to use `window.matchMedia` method:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia  And see polyfill for older browsers: https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rjx5Lt3a/ check here

Comment: Thanks @NageshwarReddy that works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a **UTF-8 BOM** Character at the end of the code, that keeps it from working. Copy this code, which is exactly same as yours but free from the character. Make sure you are using a good editor like [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function checkWidth() {
    var windowSize = $(window).width();

    if (windowSize < 950) {
      alert("test");
      console.log("screen width is less than 950px");
    }
  }
  // Execute on load
  checkWidth();
  // Bind event listener
  $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```